# Optical illusions : human universal vs environmental influences

Tags: perception, vision, cross-cultural-psychology, optical-illusion

It's well known today that the susceptibility to optical illusions are influenced by the environment: multiple studies with the [Müller-Lyer illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCller-Lyer_illusion#History) conducted in Zambia proved this environmental influence.

By I wonder if there are some optical illusions that are universal among human.

- The fact that animals (in particular birds and mammals) are subjects to optical illusions means that at least part of the illusions should be genetically influences.
- The ["perceive the present" hypothesis](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1080/03640210802035191/full), should also mean that every human should be subject to at least some illusions.

So my question is: which visual illusions are universal among humans?

To focus the question I would only consider as illusions the one that are related an increase/decrease of the size of an object/subject, or the distance (perspective) or the luminance.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this as written. It would be more amenable to answering if the question was of the form, "Are there people for whom the illusions X, Y and Z do not apply?"

Comment: I don't think that what @ChristianHummeluhr describes is the only option for rewording this question. In particular, I think that "Which sort of visual illusions are believed to be universal across human cultures?" can be a perfectly well-formed question. However, the answer might be "what do you consider an illusion?". For example, [is colour an illusion?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/4953/29) When I (and as far as I know when people of other cultures) look at my computer screen, I do not see decomposition into intensities of three wavelengths but have the illusion of their combination.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev Avoiding having to deconstruct the question with a review of what might be considered an illusion was why I suggested defining a set of illusions, but defining illusions in principle would work for me too. It's certainly not the only way to go about it, of course, just a suggestion.