# What is the neural adaptation underlying the habituation to reversed visual images?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, vision, perceptual-learning

When a person wears glasses that reverse the image upside-down, it is possible to adjust your vision in a matter of [days](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2012/nov/12/improbable-research-seeing-upside-down). What are the suggestions behind the neurological process?

Comment: Hi Probably. Could you provide a little more context? What have you learned from some initial research yourself, and why are you interested in researching this? You may edit it into your question.

Comment: @RobinKramer I haven't done my own research yet, so I'm hoping to get a very rough answer of what I could focus on.

Comment: [This is the most recent work I know on the topic](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v419/n6904/full/nature01002.html). If you could start with this paper and come back to the site with the specific questions you have, as well as the level of detail you expect in an answer, that would be awesome.

Comment: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/339/7604 may help to answer your question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**
From what I know from the literature, adapting to prism glasses mainly finds it origins in adaptation of behavioral motor control.

**Background**
The adaptation to wearing prism glasses is often ascribed to the adaptation of the proprioceptive system, i.e., subjects adapt their motor behavior to compensate for the visual field shift (e.g., [Richter *et al*. (2002)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00221-002-1097-6), [Hatada & Rosetti (2006)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00221-005-0159-y)), or through shifts in their egocentric reference frame. Admittedly, some subtle, short-lasting after-effects do seem to occur in the visual domain [(Hatada *et al*., 2006)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00221-006-0381-2), but gross adaptation is mainly centered on behavioral adaptations of motor control, at least as far as I am aware.

In four human subjects that wore prism glasses for about 36 days it was shown that after a week or two, also their ipsilateral visual cortices were activated, while normally only the contralateral cortex is activated [(Miyauchi *et al*., 2004)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ef47/04066c958c74bfd1e7344d36fe7966dd16ec.pdf). So there is a definite visuo-neurophysiological correlate of wearing prism glasses. Nonetheless The authors conclude that...

> [The] changes observed [in] adaptation to left–right reversing may be associated with the process of [...] strategic **perceptual-motor control**. [...]. For example, when the subjects wearing left–right reversing goggles pick up an object located in the left visual field, they have to use their right hand which is normally located in the right visual field [...].

Note that the [link you provide](http://www.awz.uni-wuerzburg.de/en/archive/film_photo_and_tone_archives/video_documents/th_erismann_ikohler) describes mainly anecdotal reports from a single researcher. Above studies included multiple subjects.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Hatada *et al*., *Exp Brain Res* (2006); **173**(3): 415–24](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00221-006-0381-2)

**-** [Hatada *et al*., *Exp Brain Res* (2006); **174**(1): 189–98](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00221-006-0437-3)

**-** [Hatada & Rosetti, *Exp Brain Res* (2006); **169**(3): 417–26](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00221-005-0159-y)

**-** [Miyauchi *et al*., *J Physiol - Paris* (2004); **98**: 207–19](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ef47/04066c958c74bfd1e7344d36fe7966dd16ec.pdf)

**-** [Richter *et al*., *Exp Brain Res* (2002); **144**(4): 445–57](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00221-002-1097-6)</sub>

Comment: @Probably no worries and thanks for the question :-)